# Moving JSFiddle codes to my website

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

This is probably a very basic question but I'm starting out building a website and I am struggling to move a tablesorter I'm creating on JSFiddle to my website I'm building on Wix.com

On wix you can just add HTML codes, so I'm struggling with the JavaScript codes. All the coding I've done just shows the text and the Java doesn't work.

Any help would really be beneficial.

The link to the tablesorter = jsfiddle.net/tome98/abkNM/5955/

Comment: 1) Java and JavaScript is not the same (you mentioned that the java doesn't work, that's not true at all) 2) how are you trying to move the code in the JSFiddle to your wix site? 3) i'm going to bet you didn't put the script tags right before the JS code <script type="text/javascript> {... js code goes here ... } </script>

Answer (score 1):

You can add **/show** after your jsfiddle url and see the code of the page.

In your case :

```
jsfiddle.net/tome98/abkNM/5955/show/
```

Right click -> Code of page

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851878/is-there-a-download-function-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Click on [Run] button and in another tab open the jsfiddle.net/draft/ . This will show the latest result without any iframe.