# How to download this working jsfiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

The example given in jsfiddle.net/jjx86sqb/ is excellent and would like to download all the files.

Pls let me know how to download it.

I want to run the sample html file example locally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a download function in jsFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851878/is-there-a-download-function-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply copy and paste the HTML and jQuery sections of the fiddle to your own document.

Don't forget to include the four relevant external files:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js
https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/css/dataTables.alphabetSearch.css
https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/js/dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js
```

You'll also need to reference jQuery itself (version 1.11.0 in the fiddle).

Version 1.11.0 can be found at:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

Note that jQuery must be referenced **before** the four DataTables scripts.

Your `<head>` should look like this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/css/dataTables.alphabetSearch.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-alphabetSearch/1.2.2/js/dataTables.alphabetSearch.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The jQuery code itself must be placed between `<script>` tags **after** the five external files have been included.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. and easy.

1. add `/embedded/` to the URL of the jsfiddle you want to download.
2. click on the `result` tab
3. right click on the screen and select `view frame source` (and not! view page source)
4. save the complete html you see to html file.

Answer (score -4):

It is impossible and unnecessary feature to download the code. There are max 3 codes for you to copy viz. HTML, CSS and the script.
Just click on any of the code > Ctrl+A > and copy and paste it wherever you want.
Repeat the same steps for each code.

Comment: you got (not from me) 'unnecessary' downvotes for your opinion, stated at the beginning, although the solution you suggested is good. But they need to implement that feature, which is very useful. Check codesandbox for example